# What is 社会運動標榜?

Tags: words

What is 社会運動標榜 and how is it different from 社会運動家 ?

The first is criminal in Japan and the second is not, but I'm not clear on the differences.

Props if you can also explain how this may or may not relate to a political lobby.

Ref. [社会運動標榜ゴロ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A4%BE%E4%BC%9A%E9%81%8B%E5%8B%95%E6%A8%99%E6%A6%9C%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AD)

Comment: 社会運動標榜 is not an independent noun phrase which perfectly makes sense on its own. It looks like a "fragment" to me. Perhaps you extracted this part from some sentence/phrase which you don't fully understand? Could you provide the full sentence?

Comment: I added a Wikipedia page, but really "社会運動標榜ゴロ" was used in a comma separated list of reasons to break a contract.

Comment: Okay, ゴロ is the critical noun in that phrase :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **社会運動**: (noun) "social movement"
- **家【か】**: (postfix) "-ist", "-er"
- **社会運動家**: (noun) "social activist" (neutral)
- **標榜**: (noun, suru-verb) "advocate"
- **社会運動標榜**: "social-movement-advocating"
- **ゴロ**: (noun, jargon) "public enemy", "person/group who does illegal actions" (from [ゴロツキ](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%A0%B4%E8%90%BD%E6%88%B8) "rogue", "thug")

So 社会運動標榜ゴロ is "social-movement-advocating" + "rogue". It refers to an organization that makes money by unjustifiable, illegal means, while pretending to be a benign political or social organization. For example, a group that does charity donation frauds is a 社会運動標榜ゴロ.

To be clear, the 社会運動標榜 part by itself does not have the illegal connotation. ゴロ does.